# Separating Digits in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on an exercise from my C++ book and I'm not sure how to fix it. I am supposed to get an int from the user and display the individual digits in the order they were entered. For instance 12345 would be displayed 1 2 3 4 5. 7365 would be displayed 7 3 6 5. I have most of the code written but there is a logical error and I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int divisor = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a nonzero number.";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "\nThe number you entered was " << number;
    // Determine the number of digits
    temp = number;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        temp = temp / 10;
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "\nThere are " << counter << " digits in your number.";
    // Separate the digits
    temp = number;
    cout << "\nSeparating the digits\n";
    do
    {
        divisor = (pow(10.0, --counter));
        digit = temp / divisor;
        temp = temp % divisor;
        cout << digit << " ";
        sum = sum + digit;
    }
    while (counter != 0);
    cout << "\nThe sum of the number is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter 5555 the output is 5560. When I enter 1234 the output is 1236. Can anyone help me find my error?

Comment: Side note: I don't recommend using `pow` to calculate the powers of `10`.

Comment: Far too complicated: Convert to string, insert the separators, print. Much easier.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Convert to string? Why not *read* as string?

Comment: @KerrekSB Just for fun? Maybe he'll later have another source for numbers? Of course, if he just converted from a string, collapsing both is preferable. (Also, reading a string or a number reads different input.)

Comment: I have tried debugging by hand and it looks like everything should work fine. The exercise from the book says to use an integer, so I can't use a string.

Comment: Felix, yes I saw that other post already. It is different from mine because he knows that the input will be five digits, but my assignment can be any number of digits.

Comment: @DangerousSheep Your code is working just fine, maybe you should try to recompile.

Comment: @SHR I tried closing the project and exiting netbeans. Neither worked. Still getting the wrong output. BUT...I just tried the code in Visual Studio and it runs perfectly! So the problem was not my code but something with the compiler. Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  I'm new to the community and didn't mean to do anything wrong. I did try debugging and couldn't find the error. Should I not have posted this question? I just signed up and this was my first post, so I don't really know the rules yet.

Comment: @DangerousSheep: As others have pointed out, SO is not intended for finding others to debug your code.  You should use debugging techniques *yourself* to isolate the problem, then construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I tried that. If you read the comments above you can see that it appears to be a problem with my compiler and not a debugging issue. But thanks for the warm welcome.

Comment: @DangerousSheep - The issue is more than likely not the compiler.  It may have to do with this statement: `divisor = (pow(10.0, --counter));`  You are performing floating point calculation, and floating point is not exact.  Change it to do integer-based arithmetic, as the answer given below does.

Comment: maybe also `divisor = (0.5+pow(10.0, --counter));` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one version:

```
// If the number is only one digit, print it.  
// Otherwise, print all digits except the last, then print the last.

void digits(int x)
{
   if (x < 10){
      cout << x;
   }
   else{
      digits(x / 10);
      cout << " " << x % 10;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help :-) Turns out my code works fine in another compiler so I guess it's just a netbeans glitch.

Comment: Stop fooling yourself.  The chance of the compiler having an issue is close to 0.  The compiler used by Netbeans is g++, which is used commercially in the industry by many companies and individuals.  If that compiler really had an error on a trivial program, then thousands of programmers would have reported it.